# Accessing members in a typedef map struct?

Tags: c++

My question should be simple and I've spent that last few hours trying to get an answer to it by figuring it out on my own (and google-ing) answers and getting nowhere.

I've got the following in my header file:

`Window.hpp`

```
typedef struct {
    SDL_Window* window = 0;
    const char* title = 0;
    int width;
    int height;
    int flags;
} m_windowStruct;

typedef std::map<std::string, m_windowStruct> m_windowMap;

m_windowMap windowMap; /* <-- Made this accessible */
```

and in my source file I've the following code:

`Window.cpp`

```
bool Window::createWindow(std::string id, const char* title, int width, int height, int flags) {
    m_windowMap* windowMap;
    m_windowStruct windowData;

    windowData.window = SDL_CreateWindow("insert window creation info here");

    if (!windowData.window) {
        windowData.title = title;
        windowData.width = width;
        windowData.height = height;
        windowData.flags = flags;
        windowMap->insert(m_windowMap::value_type(id, &windowData));
        SDL_LogInfo(INFO, "Window creation successful");
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Which works all fine and dandy... The problem I'm having is accessing the mapped struct members after.

For example if I want the instance of the primary window I'd want the following function:

```
/* Returns the window instance from the mapped struct */
SDL_Window* Window::getWindow(std::string id) {
    m_windowMap::const_iterator keyValuePair = windowMap.find(id); /* <-- New error: Error: expression must have a class type */

    if (keyValuePair == windowMap.end()) { /* <-- same error as just above */
        return 0;
    }

    return keyValuePair->second.window; /* <-- Same error as just above */
};
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to access the second `window` member so that I can then give it to my renderer!

Any ideas?

Comment: Oh PLEASE do not start a type name with `m_`!  PLEASE!

Comment: And please don't do the dumb `typedef struct { ... } typename;` thing. That's a holdover from C. It's only there for backward combatibility. Just do `struct typename { ... };`

Comment: And since ispin2121 answered this question, do not change this post.  If you have a _second_ question, make a new post.

Comment: @MooingDuck An answer that was deleted in this thread suggested I did the original `typedef struct {...} typename;` thing.

That being said, I've changed my code to what you've said.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want the `windowMap` being a global variable which is accessible across multiple source files (i.e., .cpp). Here are the changes you need to make,

In header file, replace the last line with `extern m_windowMap* windowMap;`. This makes variable accessible to all source files that include the header.

In your main function (or anywhere appropriate), add this line to initialize the map `windowMap = new m_windowMap();`

Remove `m_windowMap* windowMap;` in the `Window::createWindow` function, otherwise the re-declaration creates a new local `m_windowMap` and the rest of the function makes no effect to the global `windowMap`.

Lastly, since the global `windowMap` is a pointer, change `.find()` and `.end()` to `->find()` and `->end()` in the `getWindow` function.

Comment: Good explanation. As both functions seem to be part of the same class, making it a class field instead of a global variable would suffice.

Comment: OK, so using what you've suggested, I've fixed the majority of my problem except the following:

The `keyValuePair->second.window;` is throwing an `expression must have class type` error

and 

`extern m_windowMap windowMap` is throwing an `invalid storage class for a class member` error (note: this is all in a `Window` class, forgot to mention that).

Comment: So my guess was wrong if this is all in a Window class. As @nvoigt mentioned, making the map a class member is suffice.

Answer (score 0):

If the `windowMap` is indeed a class member of `Window`, it is actually easier and cleaner.

From the code you originally posted, remove `m_windowMap* windowMap;` in the `Window::createWindow` function. Otherwise the `insert` goes to this newly created local map. Also, change `->insert` to `.insert` as you did not declare `windowMap` as an pointer in the header.

Comment: I forgot to write it as `m_windowMap* windowMap;` so it is actually a pointer. See OP for what Progress I've done. (I'm still getting unseen errors)

Comment: @JamieEdwards: Do not replace one question with another.